# How to add unlimited Crypto-Strength to Java jdk8 for ARM?

Tags: java, arm

I'm running into SSL issues which indicate that `jdk-8-ea-b36e-linux-arm-hflt-29_nov_2012.tar.gz` needs to be configured for unlimited crypto-strength.

1. Where can I get the jar files to drop-in and accomplish this?
2. Do I need to build a binary flavor of jdk8-arm from source myself with some flag turned on? If so then what's the process?

Comment: You need java programmers, not raspberry hobbyists. Consider asking on stackoverflow.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a third party implementation to replace a Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) provider.

Here is a how-to from Oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablsc/index.html

You can download the recommanded implementation here:
https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty much out of luck here. Generally you do not need any native code, you need just replace limit power jars in lib directory to unlimited counterparts. But here is a catch. You can get UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8.zip from JDK 8 early access download page. But class files have version 52, however ARM JDK8 early access can't understand version 52. (I filed a bug about that). So your choice is only trying unlimited strength libraries from JDK 7. Download UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip from standard JDK 7 download page (the link is on very bottom) and follow instruction in README inside the zip. The best luck.